# How to put citations in a marginnote in the Tufte class

Tags: tufte

I'm trying to put a citation in a marginnote in Tufte's class. When I do this, the citation is displayed below, but the footnotemark does not appear.

Comment: Try using `\sidenote` instead of `\marginnote`. The former prints footnote marks while the latter suppresses them.

Comment: My question is about something different. I want to write \marginnote{this is citation \cite{sfsef} }

Comment: That's the designed behavior of citations inside of sidenotes in the Tufte-LaTeX document classes. What behavior would you prefer instead? Having sidenotes within sidenotes doesn't really work. I supposed it could be faked, though.

Comment: I would like the footnote mark to appear in the margin, with the citation appearing in a separate side note below the margin note. Is there a way to make that happen? Thanks for your help!